# If $\deg f(x) < \deg p(x)$ and $\deg g(x) < \deg p(x)$, show that $f(x)+〈p(x)〉=g(x)+〈p(x)〉 \implies f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $p(x) \in F[x]$ . If $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$ and $\deg f(x) < \deg p(x)$ and $\deg g(x) < \deg p(x)$, show that $f(x)+〈p(x)〉=g(x)+〈p(x)〉 \implies  f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x) + \langle p(x) \rangle = g(x) + \langle p(x) \rangle \implies f(x)-g(x) \in \langle p(x) \rangle$. Now use what you know about the degrees of $f$ and $g$ and the possible degree of $f-g$.

Comment: deg g(x)≺deg p(x) and deg g(x)≺ deg p(x) implies deg g(x)-deg f(x) ≺0

Comment: then deg g(x)=deg f(x)

Comment: Not quite. $\deg g(x)$ and $\deg f(x)$ are both less than $\deg p(x)$, and so $\deg f(x)-g(x) < \deg p(x)$. However, every element of $\langle p(x) \rangle$ has degree greater than or equal to $\deg p(x)$, with the exception of $0 \in \langle p(x) \rangle$. Thus, we conclude...

Comment: you mean f-g=0 since deg f(x) -deg g(x) less than deg p(x)

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding what I'm saying. Since $F$ is a field, every element of $\langle p(x) \rangle$ has degree $\geq \deg p(x)$, with the exception of $0$. We know $f(x)-g(x)\in \langle p(x) \rangle$, so $\deg(f(x)-g(x))$ is either $\geq \deg p(x)$ or $f(x)-g(x) = 0$. Since $\deg(f(x)-g(x)) < \mathrm{max}\{\deg(f(x)), \deg(g(x))\} < \deg(p(x))$, we must have $f(x)-g(x) = 0$. If this is what you mean, then yes.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)